# How to setup web2py fixtures

Tags: python, fixtures, web2py

I'm trying to find a way to create fixtures for my ***web2py*** application. I came across http://thadeusb.com/weblog/2010/4/21/using_fixtures_in_web2py that suggests creating a  **x_fixtures.py** file to place all the fixtures in. The problem is that after a while, the file gets huge and a pain to navigate through.

What I want to be able to do is have a folder named ***fixtures/*** and place all my fixtures in separate files named after the table they're for.

The Official Web2py Book says *"**tests** is a directory for storing test scripts, fixtures and mocks."*, but I haven't been able to get that to work either. The project didn't have a **tests** directory by default, so I had to create one.

Has anyone setup fixtures in this way using web2py before? If not, any suggestions on what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I couldn't figure out how to get the fixtures to work while in the directory I created ***web2py/applications/MyApp/tests/fixtures***, but I did get fixtures to work how I wanted by simply creating a ***web2py/applications/MyApp/models/fixtures*** directory and placing a separate file for each table I want fixtures for following the pattern of **x_fixtures_TABLE_NAME.py**.